# Is it possible to use import as an expression?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure if it's document somewhere but I was wondering if there's any way to use `import` of `ES2015` as an expression. The only thing I've seen it being used is with statements.

e.g. in `CJS` I can do this:-

```
require('someArray').map(arr=>arr+1);
```

but I haven't quite figured out how to do that with `import`. All I can think of is:-

```
import * as someArray from 'someArray';
someArray.map(arr=>arr+1);
```

Is it something that isn't possible with new `import` keyword?

Comment: import statements are used in static analysis, there's no place for expressions. Every possible combination is likely to be listed here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @estus Ah, I see the reason for it not being an expression now. Thank you. If you can use that as an answer I'll go ahead and close this.